# Не получается создать подключение в DataGrip к бд Postgres поднятой в Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, datagrip

Поднял контейнер с postgresql в Docker

Передал через docker-compose.yml

Следующие настройки:

```
---

services:

  postgresql_01:
    image: postgres
    container_name: gpnpartnerdb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /data/postgresql_01:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: gpnpartnerdb
```

Далее выполнил команды в консоли:

`docker ps` - Посмотрел список всех контейнеров для получения ID нужного

`docker exec -it 9047c298de43 bash` - перешёл в этот контейнер

`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W mytest` - подключился к моей дб с названием mytest

Далее в консоли был запрошен пароль я его ввёл и подключился к mytest

Затем попытался подключиться к этой бд через DataGrip
Для этого посмотрел какое подключение использует данная бд в консоли командой `\connifo`

Получил ответ :

```
mytest=#  \conninfo
You are connected to database "mytest" as user "postgres" on host "localhost" (address "127.0.0.1") at port "5432".
```

И попытался с этими данными подключиться через DataGrip к данной бд, однако это сделать мне не удалось, но я получил следующую ошибку

```
[08001] Подсоединение по адресу localhost:5432 отклонено. Проверьте что хост и порт указаны правильно и что postmaster принимает TCP/IP-подсоединения.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.
.
```

Решением это проблемы занимаюсь второй день. В Docker я абсолютный новичок. Это мой первый раз, поэтому буду благодарен за любую помощь и советы в этом вопросе.

В конце оставлю скрин настроек моего подключения в DataGrip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы у вас была возможность подключиться по `localhost:5432` вы должны сделать [публикацию порта](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports). В `docker-compose` это делается так (нужно добавить в ваш `postgresql_01` сервис):

```yml
ports:
  - 5432:5432
```

Если не хотите "открывать" порт и хост система `Linux`, то можно будет подключаться по `<container_ip>:<db_port>`, где `container_ip` можно получить через `docker inspect <имя контейнера>`.

Comment: спасибо, попробую!
Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли как - то опубликовать эти порты для уже созданного контейнера с моей дб ? Могу ли я добавить в мой docker-compose.yml информацию о портах и сделать docker-compose up ? Должно ли это сработать?

Comment: @ule если контейнер уже запущен, то нет, нужно будет сделать `docker-compose down` и потом `up`, т.к. у вас есть `volume` то данные вы не должны потерять

Comment: Спасибо! Явное указание портов оказалось одним из действий, которые помогли в решении данной проблемы